# Application hangs and getting status Pending when calling rest function call

Tags: javascript, rest, coldfusion

Coldfusion version 10.
The app hangs using IE9 when I do a REST cf function call from js file. Observing the console, I see Pending status. However, it works fine in later versions of IE, Chrome and Mozilla.

When I changed cffunction httpmethod from DELETE to PUT it worked. So, I figure that maybe javascript function call and cffunction header mismatch.

---

Here is cffunction;

```
<cffunction output="no" name="zeroUpdateCredits" access="remote" produces="application/json"  consumes="application/json" returnType="struct" httpmethod="DELETE">
  <cfargument name="DATA" type="struct" required="yes"/>
  <cfset var retStatus = StructNew() />
  <cfset retStatus["success"] = true />

  <cftry>
  <cfset var qSponsDetails = APPLICATION.cfc.properties.getsettings(DATA.employee_id)>

  <cfif qSponsDetails.allow_credits>
    <cfset temp = saveCredits(credits = 0, employee_id = DATA.employee_id, effective_date = DATA.effective_date)>
  </cfif>

  <cfcatch type="any">
    <cfthrow errorcode="401" message="error zero credits" />
    <cfreturn>
  </cfcatch>
  </cftry>                  

  <cfreturn retStatus>
  </cffunction>
```

---

Here is the function call:

```
exports.clearCredits = function(employeeId, effectiveDate){
 data = {
    employee_id: employeeId,
    effective_date: effectiveDate
};

var promise = rest.DELETE({
  url: appConfig.restPrefix + 'selections/unusedcredits?t=' + new Date().getTime(),
  contentType: 'application/json'
 }, JSON.stringify(data)
);
return promise;
};
```

Thank you,
Gena

Comment: Perhaps stick some logging in the CFML code to see if it's reaching the CF server at all. This'll help fine-tune your troubleshooting.

Comment: If I replace DELETE httpmethod with PUT, it works. I think something wrong with syntax either in javascript or cffunction header

Comment: Yeah. I saw it when you said that the first time. It has no bearing on my comment. I'm suggesting you don't *guess* what might be wrong, but instead start doing some investigation as to WHY and WHERE it's going wrong. If CF didn't like the verb, it'd throw a 500 error. Which it's not doing - from what you say - so not likely to be that.